# How to include a template that set content into blocks using twig

Tags: twig

It's difficult to explain but I have a layout.html.twig template like this:

```
{% block css '' %}
{% block content '' %}
{% block js %}
    <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
{% endblock js %}
```

I have another template index.html.twig that extends the layout one like this

```
{% extends 'AcmeBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    {% include 'AcmeBundle:Module:module_1.html.twig' %}
    {% include 'AcmeBundle:Module:module_2.html.twig' %}
    {% include 'AcmeBundle:Module:module_3.html.twig' %}
{% endblock content %}

{% block js %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script ...></script>
{% endblock js %}
```

Each included module has some javascript inside but they need to have jQuery loaded to work. 
But jQuery is set in the layout.html.twig so it's not working.

How can I include my modules being sure that the script is executed after jQuery is loaded?
Is it possible to access the js block somehow? I had a look to embed but I'm not sure it's what I need.

Any ideas?

Cheers, 
Maxime

Comment: http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/

Comment: yea maybe the issue isn't the missing jquery, its that the DOM is not ready yet, and you try to access elements that aren't yet loaded, I'd suggest like @LeroyMeijer said to use `document ready` event

Comment: I know what the issue is, I've explained it in the question. I want to know if it's possible to fix it with twig

Comment: Why not create the js block before the content block? There should be no problem if you wrap all your js/jQuery in a `$(document).ready()` ?